# Share point Link list - very new to Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am very new to SharePoint..... In my team site, I created a folder and then added Links inside the folder.  The Links work fine, but I need to figure out how to put a name next to the list so that when people come to it they will know exactly which link they need.  See the document area in the figure below.  I can't put the screen shot in here but his is on our team site page:

> Documents
>    NewUploadSyncShare    More

```
Name
portal.eyemedvisioncare.com

www.oneamerica.com

www.phpni.com

www.alwaysassist.com

www.aflac.com
```

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: I want to display the Title next to the link.  I added a title when I updated the properties for the link, but it does not display next to the link in the list of documents.  I wish I could add a screen shot.

Comment: Do you want to see both URL and title side by side?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  I can't figure out how to add the title.  Tried adding a column, but Title wasn't an option

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the title next to the name you have to update the list view. Follow below steps

- Go to library settings
- Go to Views Section and select "All Documents" view.
- Choose "Title" column from the list of columns.
- Save the changes

You should see the title next to the name (Same as in the order of columns in list view settings).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest creating the title as a link. You can do this by adding a content type that's a link.

In your library settings, under 'Content Types', select 'Add from existing site content types'. From here you should be able to select 'Link to a Document'.

Once that's done, when you click on the 'New Document' dropdown you'll see the option for 'Link to a Document'. This just calls up a box for you to enter the name and URL.